# Keep JavaScript on lowest layer?

Tags: javascript, html, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, adsense

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this to be exact, it's a situation I've never ran across before.

I have a website with a top header that's fixed, and a footer that's fixed. On the left side of the website is a GoogleAdsense ad (in JavaScript.) when you scroll down, the Top header will stay at the top (as it should.) but the JavaScript ad starts to go over the header (where the ad will show above the header.)

I've looked at the Google Ad code, and only see width/height attributes, which will do nothing to fix the problem.

I don't even have an idea as to where to begin or what to try to fix this, I've searched google a thousand times over and nothing.

How do I keep the JavaScript google ad from being on the top layer of the website and over-shadow the top fixed header?

It's just the JavaScript ad that does this, anything else will go under the Top Header like normal.

Comment: Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: what you have tried ..please share it ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting a z-index on your header in the css?

```
#yourHeader {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Freaking duh! Thank you, I didn't realize it was something so obvious.